# How to reinstall tomcat7 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7

I had tomcat7.Removed it and now am tryinh to reinstall it but am having an error.I have tried

```
apt-get purge tomcat7
```

with no success.
Here is the screenshot of the terminal.[image]

Comment: Are you with root account access?

Comment: @RobertRozas yes ofcourse

Comment: Try removing all the tomcat7 optional tomcat7 packages like tomcat7-admin....then try to install th same way yu are doing it

Comment: I have treid that too

Comment: Try following these steps http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/tomcat-on-ubuntu-install-configure-start-stop/

Answer (score 0):

I got the error,there are some packages that need to be remove before reinstalling.
You should run this command

```
sudo apt-get purge libtomcat7-java tomcat6 tomcat6-admin tomcat6-docs tomcat6-examples tomcat7 tomcat7-admin tomcat7-common tomcat7-docs tomcat7-examples tomcat7-user
```

before

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```